# get_terms with Redis Object Cache question

Tags: php, woocommerce, redis, taxonomy

By default, hide_empty => is set to be true. If Redis object cache is disabled, the below code works just fine. But when Redis is enabled, the empty term will not be hidden. It just shows all the terms. I have tried to flush the cache. The issue remains.

Any idea what may cause the issue? thanks

```
$parentid = 182;
$args = array(
    'parent' => $parentid
);
$terms = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );

if ( $terms ) {
echo '<ul>';
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    echo '<li>';
        echo '<a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ) . '" class="' . $term->slug . '">';
        echo $term->name;
        echo '</a>';
    echo '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: Can you try echoing `$term->count` to see what's in there for those terms? If you've done some manually updating of the database that can definitely get out of sync. You might also want to look into [`wp_update_term_count_now`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_term_count_now/)

Comment: They are in 0 counts. And I managed to resolve it with $term->count > 0, thanks for the hints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it with term count

```
$parentid = 182;
$args = array(
    'parent' => $parentid
);
$terms = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );
$count = count($terms);
if ( $terms ) {
echo '<ul>';
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        if ($term->count > 0){
    echo '<li>';
        echo '<a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ) . '" class="' . $term->slug . '">';
        echo $term->name;
        echo '</a>';
    echo '</li>';
}
}
echo '</ul>';
}
```